# How to call SQL Server Stored procedure in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

How to call SQL Server Stored procedure in Laravel?

Hi,

I can't call SQL Server Stored Procedure from Laravel. Coming errors.

Please help me anyone???

Comment: Which Laravel version? What have you tried? What's the error message? Show some code.

Comment: Actually,
DB::connection('mysql')->query('select * from metadata'); - is getting data.

MySQL Stored Procedure :
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts()
   SELECT * FROM users_metadata;

But,
DB::connection('mysql')->query('CALL GetAllProducts()');  - is getting Boolean value 1 only.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
DB::statement('CALL sp_user_add(:name, :email, :password);',
                array(
                    'name' => $name,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'password' => $password
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily call stored procedure in laravel in two ways

- using parameter
- without using parameter

### Without Using parameter

```
class CheckController extends Controller
{
    public function callProcedure()
    {
     // Calling Stored Procedure from MySQL
     $alluser = DB::select('call getalluser()'); 
     return $alluser;
    }
}
```

### Using parameter

```
class CheckController extends Controller
{
    public function callProcedure($id)
    {
     // Calling Stored Procedure from MySQL
     $specificuser = DB::select('call getspecificuser(?)',array($id));
     return $specificuser;
    }
}
```

You can refer the following article for better understanding
[How to call stored procedure in laravel](https://www.studywithkishan.online/2020/09/call-stored-procedure-in-laravel-7.html)